# How do you pass parameter into a pipeline script but not make it a parameterized build in the jenkins UI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How do you pass parameter into a pipeline script but not make it a parameterized build in the jenkins UI.

This script will get used in more then one place and I would like to be able to pass some values into the script but not make it a parameterized build where the users can set them.

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form, here's how you would do that.

The job that you want to pass parameters to looks like this (scripted pipeline). Let's call this job **"ParamJob"**.

```
print "Parameter passed: ${params.myParam}"
```

The job that you would kick **"ParamJob"** off with would look like this ..

```
build job: 'ParamJob' , parameters:[
                string(name: 'myParam', value: 'Test parameter')
            ]
```

And the output of "ParamJob" is

```
Parameter passed: Test parameter
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I am new to using pipelines and I am still not sure how to do this. I am currently pulling my script file called 'Jenkinsfile' from source control in jenkins. Can I append parameters in the box that takes the script path? Just to be clear I am using classic UI not blue ocean